# attr() won't change an attribute unless I return it via an anonymous function

Tags: d3.js

```
var k = -1;
someCircle.attr("cy", someScaleObject(++k));
```

All circles will have the same y alignment whereas expected behavior is to have each circle drawn below the other. Oddly enough, if I return `someScaleObject(++k)` via an anonymous function, this has the desired effect. Why? The author also declares a `d` variable within the scope of the anonymous function despite having no use for it. Can anyone explain why?

```
// Works as expected
someCircle.attr("cy", function () {
    return someScaleObject(++k);
});
```

The full code can be found below and is drawn from *D3 for the Impatient*

```
// keys.js
function makeKeys() {
    var ds1 = [["Mary", 1], ["Jane", 4], ["Anne", 2]];
    var ds2 = [["Anne", 5], ["Jane", 3]];

    var scX = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 6]).range([50, 300]),
        scY = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 3]).range([50, 150]);

    var j = -1, k = -1;

    var svg = d3.select("#keys");

    svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(ds1).enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", 20).attr("y", function (d) {
            return scY(++j);
        }).text(function (d) {
            return d[0];
        });

    svg.selectAll("circle").data(ds1).enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5).attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return scX(d[1]);
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return scY(++k); // this is what concerns me
        });

    svg.on("click", function () {
        var cs = svg.selectAll("circle").data(ds2, function (d) {
            return d[0];
        });

        cs.transition().duration(1000).attr("cx", function (d) {
            return scX(d[1]);
        })
        cs.exit().attr("fill", "blue");
    })
}
```

And the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <script src="keys.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="makeKeys()">
    <svg id="keys" width="300" height="150"></svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't passing a function with `.attr("cx", functionName(param))`, you are passing the return value of the function. This means the function is only executed once. If you wanted to pass the function you'd use `.attr("cx", functionName)`. Wrapping your function allows you to pass the parameter without executing it right away, allowing it to be executed for each element in the selection (if .attr()'s 2nd parameter is a function, it's executed for each element).

Comment: As an aside, this method of positioning does not appear to be idiomatic - `j` is equal to the index of the element, which is the second parameter in a function provided to .attr: `function(d,i){ ... }` - so it is unclear why declaring a new variable to track the index is preferable. As for having `d` in the function declaration but not using it - could just be habit that was missed in review, if it isn't used you can remove it (provided don't also use other parameters passed to the function by d3: index and nodes).

Comment: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j25ovbms/) of using the index to position the elements rather than `j` and `k`.

Comment: Excellent answers. How do I tag the question as answered?

Comment: I can post a proper answer in a little bit as only answers can be marked as answering a question, comments can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following:

```
someCircle.attr("cy", someScaleObject(++k));
```

You aren't passing a function to `selection.attr()`, you execute `someScaleObject(++k)` and pass its return value instead. If you pass something other than a function to `selection.attr()` for the second parameter, you use the same value for all elements - this is why your circles are all positioned the same.

You could pass a function without executing it:

```
someCircle.attr("cy", someScaleObject);
```

However, you want to pass some integer to this function, D3 passes three variables to the function passed to `selection.attr()` - the datum, the current index, and the  group of DOM nodes in the selection. These are passed in this order. In your case you want to pass some other variable to the function, so this method won't work.

You *could* build someScaleObject to track or access `k` itself from within the function - such that it doesn't need to be passed as a parameter. Or, we can nest the function inside an anonymous function:

```
someCircle.attr("cy", function() { return someScaleObject(++k) });
```

This allows us to pass parameters other than the datum, index, and group of nodes to the function we want to execute. This way `selection.attr()` is passed a function, that when executed for each element in the selection, execute `someScaleObject` the intended number of times.

However....

While the above is useful in terms of D3, in your specific situation, the need for passing `k` to the scale object is unclear, as `k` represents the index of each element. So instead of:

```
var k = -1;

selection.attr("cy", function() { return scY(++k); })
```

We can simply use:

```
selection.attr("cy", function(d,i) { return scY(i); })
```

Because the second parameter of a function passed to `.attr()` is the index of the element in the selection. D3 already tracks this. I'm actually not aware of a use case where the index is something that *needs* to be tracked externally.